# getExchange from mockEndPoint in a unit-test class for Camel Route Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, apache-camel, exchange-server

I want to getExchanges from a mockEndPoint in a unit-test class for Camel Route but it doesn't work.

Here is my unit test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:camel-unit-test.xml")
public class ImportDatabaseRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    @Value("${sql.importDatabase}")
    String oldEndPoint;

    @Autowired
    private ImportDatabaseRoute importDatabaseRoute;

    @Autowired
    private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return importDatabaseRoute;
    }

    @Before
    public void mockEndpoints() throws Exception {
        AdviceWithRouteBuilder adviceTest = new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                interceptSendToEndpoint(oldEndPoint)
                        .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                        .to("mock:catchCSVList");
            }
        };
        context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, adviceTest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
        JndiRegistry jndi = super.createRegistry();
        //use jndi.bind to bind your beans
        jndi.bind("dataSource", dataSource);
        return jndi;
    }
    @Test
    public void testTheImportRoute() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint mockEndPointTest = getMockEndpoint("mock:catchCSVList");
        context.start();
        List<List<String>> test = (List<List<String>>) mockEndPointTest.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody();
        assertEquals("4227",test.get(1).get(0));
        assertEquals("370",test.get(1).get(1));
        assertEquals("",test.get(1).get(2));
        mockEndPointTest.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mockEndPointTest.assertIsSatisfied();
        context.stop();
    }

}
```

And here are the results:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

```
at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.get(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:387)
```

Please help me to fix it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assert the mock before you get the exchanges. As those exchanges are the *actual* exchange that arrived at the mock. So its expectations has to be meet first, which says 1 message should arrive. And if that is success, then you can get that exchange via index 0, and you will not get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
    MockEndpoint mockEndPointTest = getMockEndpoint("mock:catchCSVList");
    context.start();

    // set expectations on mock here
    mockEndPointTest.expectedMessageCount(1);
    mockEndPointTest.assertIsSatisfied();

    // okay now we can get the exchange's from the mock
    List<List<String>> test = (List<List<String>>) mockEndPointTest.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody();
    assertEquals("4227",test.get(1).get(0));
    assertEquals("370",test.get(1).get(1));
    assertEquals("",test.get(1).get(2));

    context.stop();
```

Comment: wow, you're the best. i am reading you book right now to learn Apache Camel. Thank you so much.